# select the same vertices on view port and UV editor without selection sync? - python

Tags: python

I want to select some vertices on object and select the same vertices on the Image/UV editor but without the 'selection syn'c as it selects undesired vertices.

I wrote this script but unfortunately it does not return any UV vertices coordinates.

```
import bpy
import bmesh



obj = bpy.context.active_object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
uv_layer = bm.loops.layers.uv.verify()
bm.faces.layers.tex.verify()


bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_uv_select_sync = False

for f in bm.faces:
    f.verts[0].select = True
    f.verts[1].select = True

    for l in f.loops:
        luv = l[uv_layer]
        if luv.select:
            print(luv.uv)



bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[`BMLoop.vert`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMLoop.vert)**

---

When iterating through the face loops (, which in case below is `f.loops`), the vertex of each loop element (`l`), is the vert property [`BMLoop.vert`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMLoop.vert)   of the loop. (`l.vert`).

```
    for l in f.loops:        
        luv = l[uv_layer]
        if l.vert.select:
            print(luv.uv)
```